# Taichi X399 + Threadripper 2990wx + Ubuntu doesn't detect my USB device

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, amd-processor, motherboard

I have a USB webcam, when I plug it into MacOS or Windows laptop, it just works well.

When I plug it into my Ubuntu and run lsusb it freezes for 0.5 seconds and nothing happens.

This is what I see in `dmesg`:

```
[  191.580087] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  192.484068] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  192.484165] usb usb5-port1: attempt power cycle
[  193.704065] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  194.612081] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  194.612143] usb usb5-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[  216.524018] usb usb9-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  217.424013] usb usb9-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  217.424100] usb usb9-port2: attempt power cycle
```

I have enabled/disabled IOMMU, no change. I even tried to connect the device through VMWare directly to guest Windows OS, didn't work.

I think I also should add that I have connected numerous devices to this machine and they all work well (Canon camera, UART 3.3v, UART 5v, other WebCams, USB headsets, SD cards, eMMC to SD adapters, Smart card readers, hardware security keys, USB 3 SATA adapter, .....)

Comment: An outside possibility is an older BIOS, your hardware is pretty new., try flashing the latest update?

Comment: Already on latest BIOS update, latest OS updates. My BIOS firmware is 3.50